# OpenCV getMinFilter_GPU

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, gpu

The getMinFilter method takes (int,int,cvSize), how is OpenCv expecting me to pass a 2D image in an int?

srcType – Input image type. Only CV_8UC1 and CV_8UC4 are supported.

dstType – Output image type. It supports only the same type as the source type.

```
gpu::getMinFilter_GPU(int srcType, int dstType, const Size& ksize, Point anchor=Point(-1,-1))
```

Thanks

Comment: What makes you think you need to pass an image to that function?

Comment: the kernel is 2D so I guess the input and output must be 2D, either an image or a Mat. However the method only accepts int for both input and output.

Comment: I have not the slightest idea of opencv, but from a quick look at the documentation where it says `creates minimum filter` I would say that it creates a filter, and does not do the filtering. This seems to be consistent with the return type of `Ptr<BaseFilter_GPU>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `getMinFilter_GPU` function does not do any any filtering. It just returns a special "processor" object which is able to do filtering.

Convenient way to use gpu filtering functions in OpenCV is:

- Create a filter object (returned by `getMinFilter_GPU` and many other functions);
- Create an engine object (for example with `createFilter2D_GPU`);
- Store obtained pointer in your image processing context (you will kill all the performance if recreate the engine/filters object for each frame);
- For each input frame call apply method of the engine object to make a filtering.

I.e:

```
 GpuMat src, dst;
 Ptr<FilterEngine_GPU> filter = createFilter2D_GPU(
     getMinFilter_GPU(CV_8UC1, CV_8UC1, Size(3,3)), CV_8UC1, CV_8UC1);
 filter->apply(src, dst);
```